# Combining two CSV files into one CSV

Tags: csv, powershell, powershell-1.0

I have recently made a simple script which imports a source CSV file and creates a new column with the `Add-Member` function and then inserts data from a target CSV file into said column which then exports to a new file. My data examples of this is like so:

**NOTE: This is failing on Powershell v1.0**

**Source CSV:**

```
File Path
C:\Users\User\Documents - Filetype: xlsx
C:\Users\User\Documents - Filetype: docx
C:\Users\User\Documents - Filetype: pdf
```

**Target CSV:**

```
File Count
    0
    1
    2
```

**Outcome CSV:**

```
File Path
C:\Users\User\Documents - Filetype: xlsx
C:\Users\User\Documents - Filetype: docx
C:\Users\User\Documents - Filetype: pdf
```

Except the above is not the desired outcome I am after. Here is my code currently, I need this to work on **Powershell v1.0**, currently it does not, it works on version 2.0 and above. Here is my code and desired outcome:

```psh
$source = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Support\Path_Filetype.csv"
$target = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Support\Count.csv"
$source | % {$i=0} {
   $source[$i] | Add-Member Name 'File Count' Value $target[$i++]."File Count";
}
$source | Export-Csv "C:\Support\Path_Count.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

**Desired Outcome CSV:**

```
File Path                                        File Count
C:\Users\User\Documents - Filetype: xlsx             0
C:\Users\User\Documents - Filetype: docx             1
C:\Users\User\Documents - Filetype: pdf              2
```

Comment: You should upgrade to PowerShell v2 (or newer, if possible). All Windows versions still supported by Microsoft can run at least version 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the following code - This will get the desired results you want as it has for myself.

```
$input1 = Import-Csv -Path "C:\temp\test.txt"
$input2 = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Support\Count.csv"

$list = for ($i=0; $i -lt $input1.Count; $i++) {
      New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property @{
        'File Path'  = $input1[$i]
        'File Count' = $input2[$i]
      }
    }

$list | Export-Csv "C:\Support\Count.csv" -NoType
```